# Use Distinct with join table Mysql laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a task from my boss to display data from mysql using laravel 5.
He give me this query for SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT loans.loan_number, borrower.brate, loans.loint, loan_offer.amount,
loans.lterm,SUBSTRING(repayment_lender.repay_due_date,4,2)
FROM loans, loan_offer, borrower, repayment_lender,LENDER
WHERE loans.id = loan_offer.loan_id
AND loans.borrower_id = borrower.id
AND repayment_lender.loans_id = loans.id
AND lender.id = loan_offer.lender_id
AND lender.id = 3
```

if the query is executed it will look like this [image: Like this]

I used this code in my controller

```
 $data_loanoffers    =  DB::table('loans')->join('loans', 'loans.id', '=', 'repayment_lender.loans_id')
                                            ->join('loans', 'loans.id', '=', 'loan_offer.loan_id')
                                            ->join('borrower', 'borrower.id', '=', 'loans.borrower_id')
                                            ->join('loan_offer', 'loan_offer.lender_id', '=', 'lender.id')
                                            ->where('lender.id',$l_id)->distinct()->get();
return view('account.investor_portfolio',[
            'data_loanoffers'  => $data_loanoffers,
]);
```

And use this code in view to display data

```
 @foreach($data_loanoffers as $loans)       
                                   <tr>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{$loans->loan_number}}</div>
                                        <td> {{$borrower->brate}} </div>
                                        <td> {{$loans->loint}} </div>
                                        <td> {{$loan_offer->amount}}</div>
                                        <td> {{$loans->lterm}}</div>
                                        <td> ?? </div>
                                    </tr>

                                    @endforeach
```

Display eror in front end [image: LIKE THIS]

I'm newbie in laravel 5. and I do not know where the error of my code. maybe master here can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So.. what happens? You need to tell us your problem. Do you get the wrong result? An error message? Code becomes sentient, bent on world domination?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'loans' (SQL: select distinct `loans`.`loan_number`, `borrower`.`brate`, `loans`.`loint`, `loan_offer`.`amount`, `loans`.`lterm`, `SUBSTRING(repayment_lender`.`repay_due_date,4,2)` from `loans` inner join `loans` on `loans`.`id` = `repayment_lender`.`loans_id` inner join `loans` on `loans`.`id` = `loan_offer`.`loan_id` inner join `borrower` on `borrower`.`id` = `loans`.`borrower_id` inner join `loan_offer` on `loan_offer`.`lender_id` = `lender`.`id` where `lender`.`id` = 1)

Comment: there is an error like that in my front end

Comment: 1. Update your question with the error message instead of in a comment. 2. You are joining the table with itself without making any aliases. (MySQL don't know which `loans`-table to use in all the `loans.`-references)

Comment: I've update my question with error message. hmm, I'm not so sure how to add aliases in this case

Comment: `->join('loans as loans2', ...` and then reference with `loans2.some_column` when needed.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'loans2' (SQL: select distinct `loans`.`loan_number`, `borrower`.`brate`, `loans`.`loint`, `loan_offer`.`amount`, `loans`.`lterm`, `SUBSTRING(repayment_lender`.`repay_due_date,4,2)` from `loans` inner join `loans` as `loans2` on `loans2`.`id` = `repayment_lender`.`loans_id` inner join `loans` as `loans2` on `loans2`.`id` = `loan_offer`.`loan_id` inner join `borrower` on `borrower`.`id` = `loans`.`borrower_id` inner join `loan_offer` on `loan_offer`.`lender_id` = `lender`.`id` where `lender`.`id` = 1)

Comment: I just apply your suggest, and display error like that

Comment: `inner join loans as loans2 on loans2.id = repayment_lender.loans_id inner join loans as loans2 on loans2.id = loan_offer` - now you're joining loans _yet_ another time? You need to have a _unique_ alias _on every instance of `loans`_ you join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve my solution by using query builder from laravel

```
 $data_loanoffers        =  DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT loans.loan_number, borrower.brate, loans.loint, loan_offer.amount,loans.lterm,SUBSTRING(repayment_lender.repay_due_date,4,2) as DueDate
                                    FROM loans, loan_offer, borrower, repayment_lender,LENDER
                                    WHERE loans.id = loan_offer.loan_id
                                    AND loans.borrower_id = borrower.id
                                    AND repayment_lender.loans_id = loans.id
                                    AND lender.id = loan_offer.lender_id
                                    AND lender.id = '$l_id' ") );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select some column so that distinct can be apply on unique field.